# No display output from GPU

Tags: windows-10

Early on today I was having weird dots appear on my screen, I restarted in safe mode and the dots were gone. So I figured the problem was with software. I managed to get the latest drivers downloaded and started to install them, except halfway through my PC shut down and now my graphics card displays nothing at all! I know windows still works because I opened command prompt with win+r and typed cmd then I typed shutdown/s and a minute later my pc shutdown. Same with shutdown/r, my c restarted soon after. Please help!
My GPU is a GTX 1050 Ti

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
My gpu seems to be working now, just brushed my gpu and mobo with a paintbrush
Going to reset windows to be extra sure ^^

Comment: So a cooling issue. The "dots" on the display is often a sign of memory problems or GPU failure, which can be caused by overheating, (CPU overheat can cause similar symptoms too) and your comments about the reseating etc. allowing you to see a display is probably a matter of having enough time elapsed for the GPU to cool down. I have seen a single "dust bunny" in a heatsink cause similar issues.